# NSString and math?

Tags: nsstring, uilabel, string-formatting, nsnumber, primitive

I am newbie on Xcode. So i try to make a single app but i stuck somewhere actually i know where :D i can't write math codes i didnt understand their fundamentals please guys tell me how can i write correctly my code ;

I want to ;

dsonuc = boy text * boy text / kilo text

there is my code (i couldnt write just a simple multiplication code)

float dsonuc = dboy * 2;
idealkilo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Kutle Endesiniz %f",dsonuc];

can someone tell me what are my wrongs ?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. Numbers (primitives like int, float, etc..) in Objective C need to be wrapped with an NSNumber.

Use this:

```
NSNumber* dsonuc1= [NSNumber numberWithFloat:dsonuc];
idealkilo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Kutle Endesiniz %f",dsonuc1];
```

Also see this link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Hope this helps.